# Рекурсия. PHP7. Запрашивает очень много памяти

Tags: php, рекурсия, php7

Рекурсивная функция, которая принимает 2 параметра: a и b - и возвращает число a в степени b.

```
function stepen($a, $b) {
    if ($b <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return $a * stepen($a, $b -1);
    } 
}

echo stepen(2, 4);

?>
```

Почему если if($b = 0) , то идет переполнение памяти(сервак долго думает и потом выкидывает это: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1455423488) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in) и функция не отрабатывает, а если if ($b <= 0), то все ок?
По идеи же, если мы вводим положительное число, то ниже 0 не должно опускаться значение $b

Comment: Это причина использовать Йоды магистра нотацию :) `if (0 == $b) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать `if ($b == 0)` вместо `if($b = 0)`

Comment: Жестко тупанул. Спасибо :)

Comment: Бывает, пожалуйста! )